# Drop all SQL logins available in excel sheet

Tags: sql-server

I am new bee,

I have request from client, where he has given excel sheet with specific SQL logins and count is big enough. I'm currently using below one and doing it manually.

```
select 'drop login [' + name + '] from sys.server_principals WHERE name='ratnakar' and type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN'
DROP LOGIN [name]
```

It would be really great if someone help me out to do it in efficient way.

Comment: Just create an excel formula that builds the required SQL statement, drag it down in excel, then copy paste the result in SSMS

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try importing contents of excel file into a table in your sql server database or export excel into csv file and import it back into SQL Server temp table and open a cursor and do loop through the records and put drop statement inside the loop.

Edit:

Use bulk insert to import into temp table: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191503%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
BULK INSERT #Logins
   FROM 'C:\Logins.csv'
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      KEEPNULLS
   );
```

Open Cursor and loop through it and do the drop(https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) :

```
    DECLARE @loginName varchar(2000)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT name 
    FROM #Logins

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @loginName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        select 'drop login [' + @loginName + '] from sys.server_principals WHERE name='ratnakar' and type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN'
        DROP LOGIN [@loginName]  

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @loginName   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot.
Great help.